# Convert date type to number type( Excel ) in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to concatenate two column values into one string. One of the column has data type as `VARCHAR2(12)` and the other as `DATE`. While I am able to add them up together but the result looks something like below whereas expected output is as mentioned:

```
A=XS1297559038
payment_date=24-DEC-15
```

Input:

```
select distinct(A), A||payment_date,
```

Output:

```
XS129755903824-DEC-15
```

Expected output:

```
XS129755903842362
```

Something like we would get if we do it on Excel.

Many thanks in advance. I am using oracle sql 11.2

Comment: Where is `362` coming from?  December 15 is not the 362nd day of the year.

Comment: Hey there.. Its 24 Dec 2015

Comment: additionally A=XS1297559038

Comment: How do you convert 24 Dec 2015 to 362? Makes no sense.

Comment: How do you convert `24-DEC-15` (whatever date it means) to `42362`

Comment: Hi Kaushik.. If you convert the 24 Dec 2015 to number format in excel you would get 42362. In my previous response to Tim I had mentioned the values for A and the date that I am trying to concatenate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Microsoft's documentation for `DATEVALUE` function in Microsoft Excel,

[**DATEVALUE**](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/datevalue-function-df8b07d4-7761-4a93-bc33-b7471bbff252)

> Remarks
>
> Excel stores dates as sequential serial numbers so that they can be
>   used in calculations. By default, January 1, 1900 is serial number 1,
>   and January 1, 2008 is serial number 39448 because it is 39,447 days
>   after January 1, 1900.

So, using the logic above when I subtract your date from January 1, 1900 and add 2, I get `42362`

```
select DATE '2015-12-24' - DATE '1900-01-01' + 2  FROM DUAL;
```

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/97eade/744)

Here is a similar StackOverflow post : [Change Excel date number to Oracle date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19398908/change-excel-date-number-to-oracle-date)

Answer (score 5):

try this
select to_number(to_char(sysdate, 'J')) from dual;

Answer (score 0):

I cannot edit(less than 6 characters) or comment(less reputation :p). I think there is a need to review the output. Please check and edit if you think this is right.
    current output: XS1297559038**42**362
    expected output: XS1297559038**24**362