# How to convert text column VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE) to date format?

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I need to convert "my_date" [ date type of column  : VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE) ] column into date format as below, my table name "PROF_DATA"

```
my_date     my_date (need to convert as below)
-------    ----------
44849      15/10/2022
43890      29/02/2020
44196      31/12/2020
43769      31/10/2019
41517      31/08/2013
41501      15/08/2013
```

code which I tried

```
select CONVERT(DATETIME, substr(substr(RIGHT('0'+[my_date],6),3,0,'/'),6,0,'/'), 3) as chk_date
from PROF_DATA

********

select TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(my_date,'DD-MON-YY'), 'DD-MON-YY')
from PROF_DATA
```

But above oracle sql doesn't work ,
how should I write the code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the `my_date` value to `DATE '1899-12-30'`:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test_data ( my_date, expected ) AS
SELECT '44849', DATE '2022-10-15' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '43890', DATE '2020-02-29' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '44196', DATE '2020-12-31' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '43769', DATE '2019-10-31' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '41517', DATE '2013-08-31' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '41501', DATE '2013-08-15' FROM DUAL
```

**Query**:

```sql
SELECT DATE '1899-12-30' + my_date AS chk_date,
       expected
FROM   test_data;
```

**Output**:

> ```
> CHK_DATE   | EXPECTED  
> :--------- | :---------
> 2022-10-15 | 2022-10-15
> 2020-02-29 | 2020-02-29
> 2020-12-31 | 2020-12-31
> 2019-10-31 | 2019-10-31
> 2013-08-31 | 2013-08-31
> 2013-08-15 | 2013-08-15
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=712f3f3223e22d8199056f57787916d7)*

> **Note**: Excel stores dates as sequential serial numbers so that they can be used in calculations. January 1, 1900 is serial number 1, and January 1, 2008 is serial number 39448 because it is 39,447 days after January 1, 1900. You will need to change the number format (Format Cells) in order to display a proper date.

The 1 day out issue is an [Excel <s>bug</s> feature](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/214326/excel-incorrectly-assumes-that-the-year-1900-is-a-leap-year) where it thinks that `1900` was a leap year (it wasn't) and that day 60 was `1900-02-29` (it never existed) and all the subsequent days are one day out compared to anyone who uses the actual number of days that have occurred. If you are working with Excel dates and they are never going to be earlier than `1900-03-01` then the simple query above will work; if you may have earlier dates then use the more complicated statement [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57976078/1509264).

Comment: That's what I call retro-engineering... Well done!

Comment: I'm half expecting the OP's expected dates to be 1 day out and the query "should" be `SELECT DATE '1899-12-31' + my_date AS chk_date FROM test_data` so that day one is `1900-01-01` instead of `1899-12-31` ... but its possible that they're counting from a non-standard epoch.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `TO_DATE()` to convert your string to a date:

```
SELECT TO_DATE(my_date, 'DD/MM/YYYY')
FROM PROF_DATA
```

Then you can use `TO_CHAR()` to format the date to another format:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(my_date, 'DD/MM/YYYY'), 'DD-MON-YY')
FROM PROF_DATA
```

Comment: I tried above sql also, but it didn't work , error : ORA-29913: error in executing ODCIEXTTABLEFETCH callout
ORA-01847: day of month must be between 1 and last day of month