# SQL Query to convert number value into date

Tags: sql, oracle

In my transaction table has id Number(11), name Varchar2(25) , transactiondate number(22).

Need to write SQL query to fetch the transaction details. transactiondate should be return as date & time format instead of number.

```
transaction table 
ID   Name   transactiondate    
1    AAA    2458010   
2    BBB    2458351
3    CCC    2458712
```

I got the below result when i execute the below query

```
Select * from transaction where transactiondate <= TOCHAR(todate('2019/09/17 00:00:00', 'YYYY/MM/DD hh24:mi:ss') , 'J');
ID   Name   transactiondate    
1    AAA    2458010   
2    BBB    2458351
```

I got the query syntax error when i tried execute the below query

```
Select name, convert(datetime, convert(varchar(10), transactiondate)) as txndateformat 
from transaction;
```

Expecting query that has to be return name and transactiondate as date format instead of number.

I got below result when i execute the below query

```
Desc transaction;
Name             Null?     Type
Id               Not Null  Number(19)
Name             Not Null  VarChar2(100)
transactiondate  Not Null  Number(22)
```

Comment: What do you think which date is represented by `2456702`?

Comment: Oracle doesn't have `datetime`, are you sure you are using Oracle?

Comment: Why on earth are you storing a timestamp value in a `number` column? That's a really bad idea. Use a column defined as  `timestamp` if you want to store date & time values.

Comment: Oracle has a "Julian Date" format - which stores date as a number. It does not include timestamp.
```SELECT TO_DATE(2456702,'J') FROM dual;``` returns 13-FEB-2014

Answer (score 2):

It all depends on when you are measuring time zero from and what your units are.

Here are some typical solutions:

**Oracle Setup**:

```sql
CREATE TABLE transaction ( ID, Name, transactiondate ) AS
SELECT 1, 'AAA', 2456702 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'BBB', 2456703 FROM DUAL
```

**Query**:

```sql
SELECT name,
       TO_DATE( transactiondate, 'J' )
         AS julian_date,
       DATE '1970-01-01' + NUMTODSINTERVAL( transactiondate / 1000, 'SECOND' )
         AS unix_timestamp,
       DATE '1970-01-01' + NUMTODSINTERVAL( transactiondate, 'SECOND' )
         AS seconds_since_1970,
       DATE '1970-01-01' + NUMTODSINTERVAL( transactiondate, 'MINUTE' )
         AS minutes_since_1970,
       DATE '1970-01-01' + NUMTODSINTERVAL( transactiondate, 'HOUR' )
         AS hours_since_1970,
       DATE '1900-01-01' + NUMTODSINTERVAL( transactiondate, 'HOUR' )
         AS hours_since_1900,
       DATE '1899-12-30' + transactiondate
         AS excel_date
FROM   transaction
```

**Output**:

> ```
> NAME | JULIAN_DATE         | UNIX_TIMESTAMP      | SECONDS_SINCE_1970  | MINUTES_SINCE_1970  | HOURS_SINCE_1970    | HOURS_SINCE_1900    | EXCEL_DATE         
> :--- | :------------------ | :------------------ | :------------------ | :------------------ | :------------------ | :------------------ | :------------------
> AAA  | 2014-02-13 00:00:00 | 1970-01-01 00:40:56 | 1970-01-29 10:25:02 | 1974-09-03 01:02:00 | 2250-04-05 14:00:00 | 2180-04-04 14:00:00 | 8626-03-21 00:00:00
> BBB  | 2014-02-14 00:00:00 | 1970-01-01 00:40:56 | 1970-01-29 10:25:03 | 1974-09-03 01:03:00 | 2250-04-05 15:00:00 | 2180-04-04 15:00:00 | 8626-03-22 00:00:00
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=4ddd26daeb375a9aeb8387b5c764fb11)*

*(Note: [Excel dates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57976078/1509264) are slightly more complicated if you want to support values before `1900-03-01` but most people do not need this so there is only the simplified version included above.)*

Comment: . . Good answer.  Given the values and the database, the OP probably intends the Julian date format.

Comment: Thanks for valuable support. It is working for me                                            
Select name, TO_DATE(transactiondate, 'J') as txn_date from transaction;

Answer (score 0):

I assume that numbers are **epoch numbers**.

For SQL Server:

```
SELECT DATEADD(ss, 2456702, '19700101') --ss means interval = seconds
```

For Oracle:

```
select to_date('19700101', 'YYYYMMDD') + ( 1 / 24 / 60 / 60) * 2456702
from dual;
```