# Convert date in string format to datetime format in oracle sql

Tags: sql, database, oracle

My date column values are in the string format and shows values like '44370.4087037037','44370.4087384259'.
Whereas I want them to be in MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM format.
I have to enter it to a database in Oracle.
My query is -

```
INSERT ALL 
INTO TABLE1 (NAME, DATE_COL) VALUES ('ABC' , '44370.4087037037')
INTO TABLE1 (NAME, DATE_COL) VALUES ('XYZ' , '44370.4087384259')
SELECT * FROM DUAL;
```

How should I convert it?
I tried TO_DATE, convert, cast - didn't work
It gives an error -
[Error] Execution (5: 23): ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Comment: What dates are those strings supposed to represent?

Comment: 6/23/2021 9:36 for 44370.4087037037  and 6/23/2021 9:48 for 44370.4087384259

Comment: @NidhiKumar Is that numeric value generated by Excel? (It makes a difference as there is a bug in Excel as it thinks 1900 was a leap year.)

Comment: _"6/23/2021 9:36 for 44370.4087037037 and 6/23/2021 9:48 for 44370.4087384259 "_   And what, exactly, is the _logic_ by which that date/time is derived from that number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets assume that your value is days past 1899-12-31, then you can use:

```sql
INSERT ALL 
INTO TABLE1 (NAME, DATE_COL) VALUES ('ABC' , DATE '1899-12-31' + 44370.4087037037 )
INTO TABLE1 (NAME, DATE_COL) VALUES ('XYZ' , DATE '1899-12-31' + 44370.4087384259 )
SELECT * FROM DUAL;
```

Then, for your table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table1(
  name VARCHAR2(10),
  date_col DATE
);
```

The output would be:

```sql
SELECT * FROM table1;
```

Outputs (when `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` is `YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS`):

> | NAME | DATE_COL |
> | --- | --- |
> | ABC | 2021-06-24 09:48:32 |
> | XYZ | 2021-06-24 09:48:35 |

---

> Whereas I want them to be in MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM format.

A `DATE` column is stored as 7-bytes of binary data (1 byte each for century. year-of-century, month, day, hour, minute and second) and does **NOT** have a format.

If you want a formatted date then you need to use `TO_CHAR` in the `SELECT` statement to change it to a formatted string:

```sql
SELECT name, TO_CHAR( date_col, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI' ) AS date_str
FROM   table1;
```

Which outputs:

> | NAME | DATE_STR |
> | --- | --- |
> | ABC | 06/24/2021 09:48 |
> | XYZ | 06/24/2021 09:48 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=6fd964519fd1b8b820aede21a03bbd13)*

---

## If you are using Excel date values

From my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57976078/1509264), there is a bug in Excel where it thinks 1900 is a leap year and the numeric value it assigns days is out by one. If you want to use Excel values then, assuming all your values are going to be after `1900-02-28` then you want to use `1899-12-30` as the epoch value and not `1899-12-31`.

If you are going to have a mix of values from before and after `1900-02-28` then you can use a `CASE` expression as-per the previously linked answer.