# Convert a float value to date time in Oracle

Tags: oracle, date, datetime, type-conversion

I have a column with the following values (they are date values and were converted in Excel to numeric values), the column type is varchar however they represent float values.

```
45223.43333
45214.41042
45201.38681
45204.56944
45229.49514
```

How do I convert them to date time values?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19398908/change-excel-date-number-to-oracle-date

Comment: In excel, if you change the format to numeric, it will appear like the above values. In my case, it's an error that is received from a system, I should detect the faulty values and convert them to a specific datetime format.

Comment: Oracle stores dates as a proprietary binary format. Display format of datetime is always determined at runtime in the SQL, using functions like to_char.

Comment: Erase the cell contents, change the cell format to General, then re-copy and re-paste from your Oracle client.